# Removing a program also removes it's dependencies

Tags: software-uninstall

As you may know installing PlayOnLinux with `sudo apt-get install playonlinux` also installs Wine (if you don't have it already installed).

So I already had Wine installed, and then I installed PlayOnLinux with the command I mentioned, and then when I wanted to uninstall PlayOnLinux I did:

```
sudo apt-get purge playonlinux
sudo apt autoremove --purge playonlinux
```

Which removed PlayOnLinux as well ass Wine which was not expected.

I really don't know the difference between these two commands and I learned them from here on AskUbuntu to uninstall software.

Comment: Perhaps you just agreed blindly when *apt told you clearly what it was about to do* and then prompted you if that was okay? You can avoid surprise by reading what apt is telling you. You can also learn a lot about the commands by reading the manpages.

Comment: @user535733 that's an answer not a comment :-) `sudo apt-get purge playonlinux` returned The following packages will be REMOVED: playonlinux* and `sudo apt autoremove --purge playonlinux` returned The following packages will be REMOVED:  icoutils* libwxbase3.0-0v5* libwxgtk3.0-0v5* playonlinux* python-wxgtk3.0*  python-wxversion*

Comment: If you are saying that packages are removed without prior warning, and you can reliably reproduce it in the newest release of Ubuntu, then that would be a bug report. In a decade of Debian and Ubuntu, seen a few claims of that behavior, but nobody can reproduce it. Perhaps you will be the first....

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Simple - the autoremove option when uninstalling a package will also remove any package installed when you installed the orig. package.  In those cases the the additional packages installed are marked `automatically installed`  & will be subject to autoremoval when the orig. package is removed. So if package A installs package B when package A is removed package B would be marked for autoremoval  & removed if the autoremove command is ever used. If you wanted to remove A & keep B the you need to mark B as manually installled or just re-install B which does the same thing.

Comment: @doug thanks for the answer, how can I mark it as manually installed?